# My Query has low performance, how to improve this to get higher processing speed

Tags: oracle11g

here is my query.

```
select 
h1.cd,h2.cd,h3.cd,h4.cd,
h1.cd_nm dae, h2.cd_nm jung, h3.cd_nm so, h4.cd_nm se 
from HAKSA.HL_NCS_C h1, 
HAKSA.HL_NCS_C h2, 
HAKSA.HL_NCS_C h3, 
HAKSA.HL_NCS_C h4, 
EJ_HAKGWA_JIKMU_M e1 
where h1.cd_lvl=1 
and h2.up_cd=h1.cd 
and h3.up_cd=h2.cd 
and h4.up_cd=h3.cd 
and H1.NCS_CD_GBCD=01;
```

actually in a Toad for Oracle, it's processing speed is fast. but i use this to another program called UXStudio. And i use it that program. it takes about 3-4 seconds. And i suggested this code.

```
   SELECT
    T1.CD_NM AS NCS_DAE
    , T2.CD_NM AS NCS_JUNG
    , T3.CD_NM AS NCS_SO
    , T4.CD_NM AS NCS_SE
    , T1.CD AS NCS_DAE_CD
    , T2.CD AS NCS_JUNG_CD
    , T3.CD AS NCS_SO_CD
    , T4.CD AS NCS_CD_SE
FROM HAKSA.HL_NCS_C T1 

LEFT OUTER JOIN HAKSA.HL_NCS_C T2
ON T1.CD_LVL = '1'
AND T2.CD_LVL = '2'
AND T2.SAYONG_YN = '1'
AND T1.CD = T2.UP_CD

LEFT OUTER JOIN HAKSA.HL_NCS_C T3
ON T2.CD_LVL = '2'
AND T3.CD_LVL = '3'
AND T3.SAYONG_YN = '1'
AND T2.CD = T3.UP_CD

LEFT OUTER JOIN HAKSA.HL_NCS_C T4
ON T3.CD_LVL = '3'
AND T4.CD_LVL = '4'
AND T4.SAYONG_YN = '1'
AND T3.CD = T4.UP_CD

WHERE T1.NCS_CD_GBCD = '01' 
AND T1.SAYONG_YN = '1'
AND T2.NCS_CD_GBCD = '01'
AND T3.NCS_CD_GBCD = '01'
AND T4.NCS_CD_GBCD = '01'
```

In my thinking, this is too long. could i get a new solution?

Comment: The query processing time is spent in the data base server, no matter what client language you use, and 4 seconds it's not a bad response time for a join with 4 tables, as long you don't have to execute this very frequently.

Comment: Those two queries would appear to return rather different result sets.  In the second, you're doing left joins rather than inner joins and you're adding a whole lot of additional predicates.  How big are the tables, what is the query plan, what indexes are available, how much data is being returned, how quickly do you need the query to run?

Comment: well, i want to get data on 1~2 seconds respond time. and second query can get data on that time. I just curious about another plan.